# Create custom Terminal shortcuts

Tags: macos, terminal, ssh, shortcut, customization

I'm working a lot with SSH connections to servers, by for example forwarding localports or just establishing SSH connection to manage some servers.

For this I would like to be able to create some terminal shortcuts for example:

```
connect ssh server1
-->should run command: ssh xyx@xy
connect ssh server2 forward
-->should run command: ssh -NC user@xy -L 9999:localhost:3306
```

Is there a way to specify custom terminal commands?

Answer (score 11):

Simply add aliases in ~/.bash_profile:

If the file .bash_profile doesn't exist:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
```

Then add aliases with `nano ~/.bash_profile`. Examples:

```
alias ssh01='ssh xyx@xy'
alias ssh02='ssh -NC user@xy -L 9999:localhost:3306'
```

Then source the file or restart Terminal.app:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Entering `ssh01` in the shell will then execute `ssh xyx@xy` or `ssh02` the second command.

The alias (i.e. ssh01) mustn't be another valid command in your path (e.g ssh-add)

Comment: And if you want to define custom commands, not just aliases, just `chmod +x` an sh file (without extension) and put it in your `~/bin`.

Comment: I already had stuff in my bash_profile file, and when I appended aliases to the end of the file, they didn't work, so I had to move them to the top of the file.

Comment: In case we use zsh , we should add the source `~/.bash_profile` line at the end of `.zshrc` file at the following path: `/Users/YOUR USER NAME/.zshrc`, then restart your Terminal/iTerm2 app. The source of the answer is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352907/load-bash-profile-for-every-terminal

Comment: @awaik This may be a solution for people using both bash and zsh. People using only zsh probably want to keep their shell functions/aliases directly in zsh init files.